# The first eigenvector of a very large sparse matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Suppose I have a very large sparse `coo_matrix` (5mil x 5mil). Is there a quick and practical way to compute its first eigenvector without needing too much memory? Does `scipy` or any other package out there already could achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask you what are you computing eigenvector of? What kind of data is this.

Comment: @bodacydo Just the PageRanks of an old snapshot of Wikipedia articles.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are excellent questions and answers about the theory: See e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4368/computing-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-very-large-sparse-matrix. Plus there is information available in the sparse linalg section in the scipy documentation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs

Answer (score 3):

Scipy has some very efficient algorithms for eigenvalue-finding on sparse matrices using ARPACK. For the available methods see the docs on [Matrix factorizations in scipy.spares.linalg](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html#matrix-factorizations).

A very good read is also the tutorial on [Sparse Eigenvalue Problems with ARPACK](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/arpack.html).